# Enable only free shipping method for a specific custom field value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, shipping-method

I'm trying to add code like the one below into functions.php file. The overall function is to check products in cart and their custom fields (post_meta) called auto_delivery_default.

If its certain text in the custom field then display free shipping only, if all other text then show all other shipping methods.

Here's what I've gotten so far but I'm overlooking something making it not function right;

```
function show_free_ship_to_autodelivery ( $autodelivery_rate ) {
$autodelivery_free = array();

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
$product = $cart_item['data'];
$product_id = $product->get_id(); // get the product ID

$autodelivery = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'auto_delivery_default', true );

    if( $autodelivery == "90 Days" ) {
            $autodeliveryfree = array();
            foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
                if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                    $autodelivery_free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ! empty( $autodelivery_free ) ? $autodelivery_free : $autodelivery_rate;
    }
}
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'show_free_ship_to_autodelivery', 10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some errors and mistakes in your code… Instead, try the following that will hide other shipping methods when free shipping is available and when a cart item with a custom field `auto_delivery_default` has a value of **`90 Days`**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'show_only_free_shipping_for_autodelivery', 100, 2 );
function show_only_free_shipping_for_autodelivery ( $rates, $package ) {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ){
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_meta('auto_delivery_default') == '90 Days' ) {
            $found = true;
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }

    if( ! ( isset($found) && $found ) )
        return $rates; // Exit

    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: but is the get_meta for the product custom field or generic custom field pull?

Comment: that makes sense. Now, the only problem I'm running into is the client setup free shipping only on products over $50, any idea how I can force the free shipping option, hide all others based on the get_meta value vs $50 without changing clients settings.

Comment: Sorry @LoicTheAztec I will. :D

Comment: made a new question for that specific question if you'd want to help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430551/need-to-force-free-shipping-option-in-woocommerce)

Comment: @user1924165 Thanks, I am going to look at it…